# Moving Dynamic Classes into Dynamic Classes

Tags: jquery, dynamic, append

Problem: I am adding dynamic classes to each img (success), I am also creating a UL, and LI (Success). The li has a dynamic class as well 2 .list-1(success) Now, my last piece, is I want to move my img, inside the li class (failed). I feel I am close to a solution, but I am unable to move the Img inside the LI. Any suggestions. Forgot to add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/yw794/4/)

HTML

```
<div class="img-list">
    <img src="http://mrminix.wikispaces.com/file/view/red-number-1.jpeg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://varungenius.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/red-number-2.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-3.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    var imgNumber = $('.img-list img').length;
    var ulInfo = "<ul class='list-inf'></ul>";

    $('.img-list').append(ulInfo);

    $('.img-list img').each(function (i) {
        var liInfo = "<li></li>";
        var imgNum = ".img-list-" + (i + 1);
        $(this).addClass("img-list-" + (i + 1));
        $('.list-inf').append(liInfo);
        $(".list-inf li").each(function (i) {
        $(this).addClass("list-" + (i + 1));
        });
    });
});
```

WORKING VERSION

---

```
 $(function () {
    var imgNumber = $('.img-list img').length;
    var ulInfo = "<ul class='list-inf'></ul>";

    $('.img-list').append(ulInfo);
    $(".list-inf li").each(function (i) {
        var liInfo = $("<li></li>");
        $(this).addClass("list-" + (i + 1));
 });
 $('.img-list img').each(function (i) {
        var imgNum = ".img-list-" + (i + 1);

        $(this).addClass("img-list-" + (i + 1));
        $('.list-inf').append(liInfo);
        $(this).appendTo(liInfo);
   });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make your `liInfo` a jQuery object by prefixing `$` to your element creation. Then use [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) to append your image to the appropriate `liInfo` as such:

```
 $('.img-list img').each(function (i) {
        var liInfo = $("<li></li>");
        var imgNum = ".img-list-" + (i + 1);
        $(this).addClass("img-list-" + (i + 1));
        $('.list-inf').append(liInfo);
        $(this).appendTo(liInfo);
});
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/iradax/1)</kbd>

Also, this chunk here:

```
$(".list-inf li").each(function (i) {
        $(this).addClass("list-" + (i + 1));
});
```

Should either be outside your first `.each()`, or could be simply rewritten as:

```
liInfo.addClass("list-" + (i + 1));
```

Comment: It looks like you are placing the ul as well to?

Comment: Tried this with my current jsfiddle, no luck

Comment: Perfect, had to change a few things, but you wer right on the money.